# how to separate information from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

[image]

Is it possible to make another array where only the information of "latitud" and "longitud"?

more clean like this:

[image]

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it will be easier to help you if you pasted the data as text and not as an image.

Comment: Array.map is your best friend. const latLngOnly = array.map(({latitud, longitud}) => ({latitud, longitud}))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a nested [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the wanted properties and return an array.

```
newData = data.map(a => a.map(({ latitud, longitud }) => [latitud, longitud]));
```

Comment: I had the exact same answer, would you believe missed it by that much. Nice job! :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but I do not understand how this could work.

Comment: if you add some data, in text form, i could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your array is in `data` (working example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/bvL1xpf4/1/)) :

```
data.map(x=>x.map(y=>[y.latitud, y.longitud]));
```

Comment: but in this way that you say you can create another array?